# Meteor acounts add info from Twitter accounts

Tags: twitter, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to figure out how I can add additional information from a user's Twitter account to the created account on a Meteor installation.

In particular I am trying to access the user's bio via Twitter Api v 1.1 and am not successful in doing so.

Therefore I am trying to extend `Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options,user) {});` with the Twitter bio. How do I do that? And then access this data from a template?

Here's a perfect answer for returning data from Github, however I've had trouble porting this approach over to Twitter as the authenticating service: [Meteor login with external service: how to get profile information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660219/meteor-login-with-external-service-how-to-get-profile-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it on this way:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user){
   user.profile = options.profile || {};
   //Twitter returns some useful info as the username and the picture
   if(user.services.twitter){
       user.profile.picture= user.services.twitter.profile_image_url_https;
       user.profile.username= user.services.twitter.screenName;
   }
   return user;
});
```

For getting the data from the Twitter API I´m using the node package oauth:

```
OAuth = Npm.require('oauth');
oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    'consumerKey',
    'secretKey',
    '1.0A',
    null,
    'HMAC-SHA1'
);
getTwitterUserData: function (id) {
    var accountUser = AccountsUserCollection.findOne({_id: id});
    var url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name="+accountUser.screen_name;
    oauth.get(url, 'accessToken', 'accessSecret', function (err, data, response) {
       if(err){
          console.log(err);
       }
       if(data){
           Fiber(function () {
               AccountsUserCollection.update({_id: accountUser._id}, {$set: {dataTwitter:    JSON.parse(data)}});
           }).run();
       }
       if(response){
           Log.info(response);
       }
    });
}
```

Comment: I understand that onCreateUser is the right way to do it. Screen name and profile image are provided by Meteor, but the rest needs to be called via the API. I just don't understand how I'd get that to work so far @lfergon.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I misunderstood you. You can make a call to Twitter API because you have the accessToken on user account, I will update my answer.

Comment: Wow thanks @lfergon. I'm such a complete beginner therefore I'm trying to make sense of it. Unlike the onCreateUser method this one doesn't save it to the database, but calls it from the API, correct? How do I call - let's say - the bio within a template? I know these are the very basics...

Comment: You could call the method getTwitterUserData(id), get the data associated with the user once, save to database and on that way you have always the info available.

Comment: Looks great. Assuming I want to just access the user bio from the template (no need to save to the database I guess). What steps do I need to take? I'm ok with a hint in the Meteor docs to figure it out. Anyways, this is helping a lot, thank you.

Comment: In that case if you want to call Twitter API from the template you can do it with an ajax call to Twitter API and process the answer.

Comment: I'm going to mark it as solved. Anyways if you care to send me to some relevant documentation regarding the ajax call to Twitter in relation to the Meteor templates, that would be great (if anything like it exists).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681182/how-to-call-twitter-v1-1-api-in-javascript-using-ajax